# SQL Query result needed as variable for multiple php files sourced from Index

Tags: php, include, organization, global

I am using the user's IP address to find the closest airport to the user's location, using the Haversine formula, and at the end, assign the result to my variable, $AirportID.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $AirportID = $row[Airport];
    }
```

I have 5 other php/sql queries (that are included in my index.html) that require this variable to query a database. Is there an easier and more elegant way to refer to this closest Airport ($AirportID) for all the files vs. having to include/run the locator script on every single php script?

Thank you Stack Overflow Community!

Comment: Is your `$result` only returning  1 row? It would not make sense to reassign the `$AirportID` multiple times if you have additional rows being returned from `$result`.

Comment: Yes one row (LIMIT 1) for the closest airport.

Answer (score 0):

Once you collect the `$AirportID`, you can store it in a `$_SESSION` variable, and then have the other queries use that value.

Using this block of code, it will maintain the `AirportID` as long as the user has an active session cookie, which usually will auto-delete when they close the browser.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['AirportID'])) $AirportID = $_SESSION['AirportID'];
else {
// Look it up if it doesn't already exist

 $result = mysqli_query('<your query> LIMIT 1;');
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $AirportID = $row['Airport'];

 $_SESSION['AirportID'] = intval($AirportID);
}
```

---

I changed the code to reflect that you are retrieving only one row. No need for the `while` loop.

Also, never forget the quotes around a field name. It will cause PHP to first check if there is a constant named `Airport` first before it then checks for a field name.

Keep in mind, that if there is a form that allows them to change this value, or if their IP changes, the session variable should be `unset`:

```
unset($_SESSION['AirportID']);
```

Comment: I had an error in it, called the wrong variable, should be good now.